# What are monadic bind and monadic return for C++23 optional?

Tags: c++, monads, stdoptional, c++23

C++23 `std::optional` is finally getting some very useful additions.

Since my knowledge of FP is very primitive I am wondering what is the syntax for the following two operations(that according to my googling are 2 basic monadic operations):

1. monadic bind
2. monadic return

My best guesses are:

monadic bind is [transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/transform)

monadic return is just C++17 `std::optional` [constructor(8)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional)

Comment: Why not read [the proposal itself](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0798r6.html)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### `mbind` (it doesn't exist, I'm mimicking Haskell's `>>=`)

In C++-like pseudo-code, the monadic binding, let's call it `mbind`, should have such a signature:

```cpp
C<U> mbind(C<T>, std::function<C<U>(T)>);
```

i.e. it should take a monad `C` on some type `T`, a function that "pulls ***the inside*** of that monad out" and turns into a monad `C` on a (not necessarily) different type `U`, `C<U>`, and gives you back that `C<U>`.

### `transform` (the free function)

The `transform` you mention, first of all, is a member function, and it has a signature kind of this

```cpp
C<U> C<T>::transform(std::function<U(T)>);
```

but let's rewrite its signature as it would be if it was a free function:

```cpp
C<U> transform(C<T>, std::function<U(T)>);
```

so as you see it takes a `C<T>` and applies a function from `T` to `U` ***right inside the functor `C`***, thus resulting in a `C<U>`.

### So there's a difference.

To better understand what the difference is, try passing `transform` a `C<T>` and a function with signature the one that `mbind` expects, `std::function<C<U>(T)>`.

What do you get? Remember that `transform` applies the function "right inside the functor, without pulling anything out", so you get a `C<C<U>>`, i.e. one more functorial layer.

`mbind`, instead, with the same two arguments, would have given you a `C<U>`.

And how can you go from what `transform(x, f)` returns to what `mbind(x, f)` returns, i.e. from a `C<C<U>>` to a `C<U>`? You can just flatten/join/collapse/whatever-you-want-to-name-it the two functorial levels, via what's called `join` in Haskell and `flatten` in some other language.

Obviously if you can do that (and you can for `C = std::optional`), then those "functorial layers" were actually "monadic layers".

### So is there an `mbind`-like thing?

As suggested in the other answer there's the `and_then` member function.

Is `and_then` the (non-existing) `mbind` I've mentioned above? Yes, with the only difference between them being the same as between `transform` member function and `transform` free function: one is member and the other is free.(†)

### And where's `flatten`/`join`, by the way?

You might wonder if there's this utility in C++23. I have absolutely no clue, I'm barely aware of what C++20 offers.

However, since the function that makes `std::optional` a functor is defined as a member function of `std::optional` itself, I strongly believe that if there was monadic binding function for `std::optional`, it would be defined as a member function too, and in that case it would be [at this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), in the section **Monadic operations**, together with `and_then`/`transform`/`or_else`. Since there isn't, I tend to assume it doesn't exist.

But some knowledge of Haskell helps me give you an idea of why it might be unnecessary to add it to the standard.

What happens if you do this?

```cpp
auto optOfOpt = std::make_optional(std::make_optional(3));
auto whatIsThis = optOfOpt.and_then(std::identity{});
```

Yeah, that's it: calling `.and_then(std::identity{})` on a nested optional is equivalent to the wannabe `.join()`.

### What about other libraries?

[Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) defines concepts for `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, and many others, giving you a way to implement automatically all the abstractions that leverage those concepts at the cost of giving some minimal definition. For instance, if you define `transform_impl` and `flatten_impl` in `namespace boost::hana` for `std::optional`, that enables you to use on it `transform`, `flatten`, `chain`, `ap`, and any other operation that requires a monad or less.

The following is working code, for instance ([complete example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/x5P6jdPoY)):

```cpp
    auto safeSqrt = [](auto const& x) {
        return x > 0 ? std::optional(std::sqrt(x)) : std::nullopt;
    };
    {
        auto opt = chain(std::optional(2), safeSqrt);
        std::cout << opt.value_or(-1) << std::endl; // prints sqrt(2)
    }
    {
        auto opt = chain(std::optional(-2), safeSqrt);
        std::cout << opt.value_or(-1) << std::endl; // prints -1
    }
    {
        auto opt = chain(std::nullopt, safeSqrt);
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(opt), std::nullopt_t>); // passes
    }
```

---

(†) Originally I stressed a bit more on `and_then` not being `mbind` because the former is a member function, the latter is a free function.

The reason why I stressed it is that member functions "belong" to classes (in the sense that you can't have a member function without having the class which it is a member of), so in some way the `and_then` we discuss here is totally unrelated to the namesake function that we'd write to make `std::vector` a monad, because that would live inside `std::vector`.

On the other hand, the non-member `transform` and the hypothetical `mbind` are free functions, so they exist without any need for any class, and so they look a bit more like interfaces to some general abstractions that types can opt in to (like Haskell's type classes). It's clear that, assuming `std::transform` and `mbind` were customization point, client code that wants to opt in for some type would have to write a customization for that type, and maybe that could leverage a member function.

---

Answering to this question made another question pop up in my mind, so [I've asked it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70640158/could-stdrangesviewstransform-one-day-support-any-functor).

Comment: "Is it the non-existing mbind I've mentioned above? Not quite, but it is quite: .and_then is to mbind what .transform is to transform." I have no idea what you're trying to say here

Comment: Better now, @Barry?

Comment: `and_then` _is_ the monadic bind operation, so I don't know why it's "not quite"

Comment: I've written it (`and_then`, the member function) isn't quite the `mbind` I've written above (the free function), just like the member function `transform` is not the free function `transform`. As simple as this, @Barry. If stressing to much on the difference between member and non-member seems uselss, then I'm removing it ritght now.

Comment: @Barry do you know if there is a flatten/join mentioned as missing in this answer? I could ask a separate question, but seems a small detail that it might be nicer if added to this answer, obviously if Enlico agrees.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, I've added a reasoning why I think it doesn't exist. Don't know how convincing it is.

Comment: @Enlico thank you... but maybe there is something in ranges code that can do this, but I doubt it... since I doubt ranges code even knows about std::optional, let alone C++23 changes.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, well, as I wrote, `.and_then(std::identity)` _is_ the wannabe `.flatten()`. I doubt anything simpler than this is provided. Otherwise it would be named `flatten`, or `flat`, or `join` (`<ranges>` and Range-v3 do have `join` but it's again the one for ranges). However, maybe Barry knows something more.

Comment: Btw, I've asked [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70640158/could-stdrangesviewstransform-one-day-support-any-functor).

Comment: Do we need brace after the identity in order for this to work `auto whatIsThis = optOfOpt.and_then(std::identity{});`

Comment: @roi_saumon, yes, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

Not quite.

In Haskell syntax, bind is of the form `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, which corresponds to satisfying this concept (for all `A`, `B`, `F`)

```
template <class Fn, class R, class... Args>
concept invocable_r = std::is_invocable_r_v<R, Fn, Args...>;

template <class Bind, template <class> M, class A, class B, invokable_r<M<B>, A> F>
concept bind = invocable_r<Bind, M<B>, M<A>, F>;
```

That's [`and_then`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/and_then) (with `this` bound to the first argument). `transform` is fmap (with `this` bound to the second argument), which is the Functor operation (all Monads are Functors).

`fmap` is of the form `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

```
template <class Fmap, template <class> M, class A, class B, invokable_r<B, A> F>
concept fmap = invocable_r<Fmap, M<B>, M<A>, F>;
```

The difference is in the return type of the function being bound or mapped.

Another example of this distinction is .NET's linq [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) vs [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0)

Another nitpick is that the monad laws discuss expressions, not statements, so you'd have to wrap the constructor in a function.

Comment: Could you expand this a little bit? Because I'm missing the point. I know C#, C++ and have looked a little at Haskell. I think the difference between Select and SelectMany is that the latter flattens a returned list-of-lists. And I know what `andthen` would do as in more like a "Fluent syntax". But I don't fully relate this all.

Comment: @JHBonarius, the monadic binding is transform followed by flattening. However they are defined for the specific  wannabe-monad.

Comment: @JHBonarius they are applicable to different functions. If you have `function<B(A)> f` and an `optional<A> a`, you use `a.transform(f)` to get an `optional<B>`. If instead you have a `function<optional<B>(A)> f` then you probably want `a.and_then(f)` to get an `optional<B>`, rather than an `optional<optional<B>>` that `transform` would give you

Answer (score 3):

> monadic return is just C++17 std::optional constructor(8)

Yes.

> monadic bind is transform

No.

Monadic bind accepts a function that of type `T -> std::optional<U>`. If you just map/transform with such a function, you will get a `std::optional<std::optional<U>>`

```cpp
auto continuation = [](T t) -> std::optional<U> {...};
std::optional<T> opt{...};
std::optional<std::optional<U>> out = opt.transform(continuation);
```

but with monadic bind (spelled `std::optional::and_then`) we get just one optional out:

```cpp
std::optional<U> out = opt.and_then(continuation);
```

This is what monads are (map then flatten) and why they exist to chain together functions of kind `T -> Monad<U>`

---

**Edit**: I'd argue `flat_map` is the best name for monadic bind, since mapping then flatting out the nested types is what it actually does. And this is how monads should be taught (with `optional`/`future`/`range`) rather than the ridiculous Haskell types and their stupid do notation. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794076/11998382) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71907811/useful-monads-for-multi-paradigm-languages/71964746?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C13.2754#71964746).

Comment: @PaulD haskell uses `k` rather than `c` to stand for "kontinuation"