# Could std::some-namespace::transform one day support any functor?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, monads, functor, c++23

[`std::transform` from the `<algorithm>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) applies to ranges, and it is what "enables" us to use ranges as the functors they are (***in the sense of category theory***(¹)). `std::transform` is iterator-based, yes, but [`std::ranges::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) is not, and its signature closely matches the signature of corresponding functions in functional languages (modulo the different order of the two arguments, but this is not a big deal).

When I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606173/what-are-monadic-bind-and-monadic-return-for-c23-optional/) (and in the process of [answering to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70606806/5825294)), I learned that C++23 introduces [`std::optional<T>::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/transform), which makes `std::optional` a functor too.

All these news truly excite me, but I can't help thinking that functors are general, and that it'd be nice to have a uniform interface to `transform` any functor, as is the case in Haskell, for instance.

This makes me think that an object similar to `std::ranges::views::transform` (with a different name not alluding to `ranges`) could be made a [customization point](http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/) that the STL would customize not just for ranges, but also for `std::optional` and for any other functor in the STL, whereas the programmer could customize it for their user-defined classes.

Quite similarly, C++23 also introduces [`std::optional<T>::and_then`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/and_then), which is basically the monadic binding for `std::optional`. I'm not aware of any similar function that implements monadic binding for ranges, but C++20's `some_range | std::ranges::views::transform(f) | std::ranges::views::join` is essentially the monadic binding of `some_range` with `f`.

And this makes me think that there could be some generic interface, name it `mbind`, that one can opt in with any type. The STL would opt in for `std::optional` by implementing it in terms of `std::optional<T>::and_then`, for instance.

Is there any chance, or are there any plans that the language will one day support such a genericity?

---

<s>I can certainly see some problems. Today `std::ranges::views::transform(some_optional, some_func)` is invalid, so some code might be relying on that via SFINAE. Making it suddenly work would break the code.</s> [No quite, breaking code that relies on SFINAE-based detection of invalid code is ok.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75549705/can-the-standard-allow-or-would-run-into-contradictions-calling-a-member-funct#comment133292981_75549706)

---

(¹) As regards the word *functor*, I refer to the definition that is given in category theory (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776030/5825294)), not to the concept of "object of a class which has `operator()` defined"; ***the latter is not defined anywhere in the standard*** and is not even mentioned on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/), which instead uses the term [FunctionObject](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FunctionObject) to refer to

> an object that can be used on the left of the function call operator

Comment: Is there some technical reason that makes you think adopting these changes would be impossible/hard?

Comment: @idmean, I've mentioned one possible problem. SFINAE code relying on the non validity of some code would break.

Comment: I can only speculate, but I find it very unlikely. It was painful enough getting those `optional` operations in. I don't personally see the committee embracing category theory for the future even if there are certainly people on it who are familiar with Haskell or similar.

Answer (score 3):

> And this makes me think that there could be some generic interface, name it `mbind`, that one can opt in with any type. ...
>
> Is there any chance, or are there any plans that the language will one
> day support such a genericity?

There is [P0650](https://wg21.link/p0650) which proposes a non-member monadic interface, customizable using traits. The paper shows customizations for `expected` and other types, implementable in C++17.

The accepted proposal for `std::optional` monadic operations [P0798 §13.1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0798r8.html#other-solutions) references P0650 while discussing alternatives to member-function syntax:

> Unfortunately doing the kind of composition described above would be very verbose with the current proposal without some kind of Haskell-style `do` notation
>
> ```cpp
> std::optional<int> get_cute_cat(const image& img) {    
>    return functor::map(
>        functor::map(
>          monad::bind(
>            monad::bind(crop_to_cat(img),
>              add_bow_tie),
>            make_eyes_sparkle),
>         make_smaller),
>      add_rainbow);
>  }
> ```
>
> My proposal is not necessarily an alternative to [P0650]; compatibility between the two could be ensured and the generic proposal could use my proposal as part of its implementation.

It goes on to mention how other C++ features still in development, like unified call syntax, might provide a more concise syntax for generic monadic operations.

The accepted proposal for `std::expected` monadic operations [P2505](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2505r5.html#org9e312b1) doesn't reference P0650 directly, but discusses "Free vs member functions" as part of its design considerations, ultimately prioritizing consistency with the `std::optional` monadic interface.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not aware of any similar function that implements monadic binding for ranges, but C++20's `some_range | std::ranges::views::transform(f) | std::ranges::views::join` is essentially the monadic binding of `some_range` with `f`.

`ranges::views::for_each` is monadic bind for ranges ([read](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/17/c-ranges-are-pure-monadic-goodness/)), although it is just `views::transform | views::join` under the hood.

As for whether you'll get a generic interface for Functor and Monad. I doubt it unless such genericity will be useful to library writers writing templates. `std::expiremental::future` is monadic also (and I imagine Executors are too), so one could to write generic algorithms such as `foldM` over these three types. I think Erik Niebler has shown with range-v3 that it is possible to write a Functor/Monad library at the expense of hand coding every pipe operator i.e.

```
#include <fp_extremist.hpp>
template <typename M> requires Monad<M>
auto func(M m)
{
    return m
        | fp::extremist::fmap([](auto a) { return ...; })
        | fp::extremist::mbind([](auto b) { return ...; })
        ;
}
```

What I think is actually possible, is that we'll get UFCS and a `|>` operator so we can get the benefits of `invocable |> east` syntax and the ability to pipe to algorithms. From [Barry's blog](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/08/22/ufcs-custom-extension/):

> It doesn’t work because while the range adapters are pipeable, the algorithms are not. ...
>
> That is, x |> f still evaluates as f(x) as before… but x |> f(y) evaluates as f(x, y).

P.S. it's not hard to give the definition of a Functor in c++: `<typename T> struct` that provides `transform`.

P.S.S
**Edit**: I realised how to handle applicatives.

```
Applicative<int> a, b, c;
auto out = a
    | zip_transform(b, c
        , [](int a, int b, int c){ return a + b + c; })
    ;
```

`zip_transform` because it zips `a`, `b`, `c` into a `Applicative<std::tuple<int, int, int>>` and then transforms it (think `optional`, `future`, `range`). Although you could always work with Applicatives of partially applied functions, but that would involve lots of nested functions which is not the style of c++ and would disrupt the top to bottom reading order.