# What's the difference between C++23's optional::transform and optional::and_then?

Tags: c++, monads, monad-transformers, stdoptional, c++23

C++23 adds some "monadic-style" functionality regarding optionals, as methods of `optional<T>`:

[`optional<T>::and_then()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/and_then) (and ignoring qualifiers of `this`):

> ```
> template<class F> constexpr auto and_then(F&& f);
> ```
>
> Returns
> the result of invocation of f on the contained value if it exists.
> Otherwise, returns an empty value of the return type.

[`optional<T>::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/transform) (and ignoring qualifiers of `this`):

> ```
> template<class F> constexpr auto transform(F&& f);
> ```
>
> Returns an `std::optional` that contains the result of invocation of `f` on the contained value if `*this` contains a value. Otherwise, returns an empty `std::optional` of such type.

So, aren't these two functions doing the same thing?

Comment: I'm surprised thatn when you asked this question, using that title wording and those tags... the existing answered question didn't popup among the suggested: [What are monadic bind and monadic return for C++23 optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606173/what-are-monadic-bind-and-monadic-return-for-c23-optional) Because beside the slight difference in perspective (what's the difference between X and Y vs what is Y), it's an exact duplicate imho.

Comment: @Enlico I think the Haskell perspective and the mentions of Haskell in the answer to the other question make it too cluttered and distracting as an answer to this one. I have added a link to that answer in my own answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Suppose you have an `optional<T1>` value.

- `transform()` lets you pass your optional to functions like `T2 foo(T1 x)`;
- `and_then()` lets you pass your optional to functions like `optional<T2> bar(T1 x)`;

... and get an `optional<T2>` at the end. So, `transform()` will "re-box" the function's output into an optional, while `and_then()` will expect the function to return a boxed value on its own.

You might also think of `transform` like `std::transform`: You apply a function to "each element"; in a container, it may be any number of elements, and in an optional, it's either 0 or 1 elements.

<sub>See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606173/what-are-monadic-bind-and-monadic-return-for-c23-optional).</sub>

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: You're right, but - then my answer doesn't really explain why this even makes sense. I mean, if we get an optional both with `and_then` and with `transform` - what's the use of having both of them?

Comment: Fluent API is enough reason for me personally.

Comment: @einpoklum The point of monadic operations is to keep the object as an `optional`, and only unwrap them after you've finished all operations. `and_then` expects functions that were written for `optional`, where `transform` makes non-`optional` functions usable in `optional` context.

Comment: In case anyone might come for the `std::expected` side, `and_then` is actually `and_then_when_valid`, `or_else` is actually `or_else_when_invalid` taking `expected<T1,E2> fred(E1 x)`. In other words, `and_then` ***automatically*** passes through `E1` (`nullopt_t`) and `or_else` ***automatically*** passes through `T1`. Yes, `transform_error` and `or_else` are the `std::exptected`'s the counterpart of `transform` and `and_then` and their parameter function take a parameter of `E1` instead of `T1`.

Answer (score 1):

`and_then` only takes functions of type `T -> std::optional<U>` (whereas `transform` is free to take functions returning any type).

If you just `transform` with such a function you will get a `std::optional<std::optional<U>>`.

`and_then` just then flattens the `std::optional<std::optional<U>>` into an `std::optional<U>`.

That's all monads are: `transform` composed with a type level `flatten`. Think `range<range<U>>` and `future<future<U>>`.

Comment: "That's all monads are". Not quite. You can write such a thing for `map` (with a fixed key type), but `map` is not a monad. Not that it matters...

Comment: @n.m. thanks I assume you mean `std::map<T, std::map<T, U>>`  can be flattened but isn't a monad. I'll think about it later

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

`and_then` is monadic `bind` aka `flatmap` aka `>>=` and `transform` is functorial `map`.

One can express `map` in terms of `bind` generically, but not the other way around, because a functor is not necessarily a monad. Of course the particular monad of `std::optional` can be opened at any time, so both functions are expressible in terms of ordinary pre-C++23 `std::optional` API. Thus the question why the C++ standard defines both functions is no better than the question why it defines any of the two. Perhaps the Standard wishes to give the programmer a standard functorial interface and a standard monadic interface independently. Either interface is useful and important on its own right.

Comment: C++ programmers have different notions associated with the words "bind", "map" and "flatmap"; and the operator `>>=` does not exist in C++. Please explain all of this in your answer, or provide appropriate links.

Comment: @einpoklum I have considered this idea and decided against it. This answer is not, and doesn't want to be, an introduction to functional programming.

Comment: But the target audience of your answer does not understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @einpoklum I am of a somewhat different opinion about my target audience. If I'm wrong, anyone can write a better answer or edit this one.

Comment: @einpoklum Technically, C++ *does* have an operator called `>>=`, and I wouldn't be surprised if operator overloading were flexible enough to let you make it mean `and_then`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: Indeed, C++ has a "left-shift-equals" operator. But that's not the operator `>>=` n.m. was referring to. However - that is an interesting idea.

Comment: This reply is only just more cryptic than the standard wording. It is not comprehensible for average C++ programers, even some of the elite. Nobody can edit such an answer propperly, except the author himself.